# Multiplication of numbers by themselves

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am practicing for loops and for one of the end-of-the-chapter exercises, it is asking to create a multiplication table that show the results multiplying the integers from 1 to 12 by themselves. This is what I did, which produces a wrong result. I am sure I am missing something simple but can't catch it.

```
public class PP63 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int TOTAL = 12;


        for(int i = 1; i <= TOTAL; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j<=TOTAL; j++)
            {
                System.out.println(i*j);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: For future questions, please be clear about what you mean by "produces a wrong result". It's pretty obvious in this case but for complex issues so many questions lack adequate information.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Which is why you down voted?

Comment: No, I didn't downvote you, although I can see why others would.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want a table, not a list

```
for(int i = 1; i <= TOTAL; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j<=TOTAL; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(i*j + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: You may want to print spaces after each result. :D

Comment: I tested it out: using tabs looks pretty sexy!

Answer (score 1):

One issue here is this line:

```
System.out.println(i*j);
```

Notice that this is calling `println`, which prints the value on its own line.  If you want to print multiple values on the same line, you can use `System.out.print` instead.  You'll need to manually insert whitespace to make sure everything aligns properly and will have to insert your own newlines as well.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to you problem i think you are getting all the result mixed in one line so you should do it like this way :

```
public class PP63
    {
       public static void main (String[] args) {

          // print main table
          for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
             System.out.print(i + ":");
             for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++) {
                System.out.print(i*j + " ");
             }
             System.out.println();
          }
       } // end of main
    }
```

Comment: Uh, so how does this improve over jh314's answer? It has arguably poorer formatting and hard-coded constants.

Answer (score 0):

use this code inside your main method. I hope you would like it

```
    final int TOTAL = 12;

    for(int i = 1; i <= TOTAL; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j<=TOTAL; j++)
        {
           if(i*j<10)
              System.out.print(j+"*"+i+" = "+i*j +"     ");
           else if(10<=i*j & i*j<100)
              System.out.print(j+"*"+i+" = "+i*j +"    ");
                   else if(100<=i*j & i*j<1000)
              System.out.print(j+"*"+i+" = "+i*j +"   ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```